Home water pressure higher than city water pressure?
Is it possible for home water pressure to be higher than the city?
The home reads 140 psi (965 kPa) while city says their psi is set at 107 psi (738 kPa).

Since the two measurements were taken with different gauges, it is impossible to know if the discrepancy is real or not. Presumably, the city used a calibrated gauge Ibut unknown accuracy) and your gauge is probably of unknown calibration or accuracy. Ask the city to come and measure your pressure with their equipment.

Questions with more context will get much better answers on this forum :) Why does it bothering you? What tool are you using? Where did you test it? What kind of home? Apartment or SFH?

Both 107 and 140 are too high (at least for the pipes used in residences in the US).  You should probably get a pressure reducing valve to reduce it to between 20 and 80.  The 50 to 60 range would be good.  If not in the US, consult a local plumber.

Where is this property located, state and city?

Your city's spec - "their psi is set at 107" - most likely has more to it, like a certain place, under specific circumstances. IOW, they set their pumps so that the pressure is 107 at the main or as it comes into a home. The actual pressure is probably higher in some places since it will drop as the water pushes through miles of mains and valves and taps, and when other people are using it.

If your house is 76 feet (23 metre) lower (0.433 psi per foot ; 9.79 kPa/m) than the place where they measured the pressure then yes, else no.
This is because water pressure increases with depth. This works in the ocean, works in a dam, and even works in pipes.

It is possible to develop higher pressures in a home than the city supply if there is a tank water heater, the house has a check valve in the incoming cold water line, and there is no pressure stabilization tank.
What happens is that the household uses a lot of hot water at one time, then uses no water hot or cold (everybody leaves for school or work). Water (hot and cold) is then trapped by the check valve.
The temperature of the water in the tank is raised by the burner and expands. This raises the pressure to the value of the PTV relief on the hot water outlet of the tank at which point the valve opens and a small amount of water is released. This lowers the pressure to the value of the PTV. This pressure would be higher than the city mains pressure.
Where I live houses are not fitted with check valves in the incoming water line, and I am told the city does not fit check valves in or at the water meter. Therefore this pressure rise cannot happen and houses do not need or have pressure relief tanks. The city mains pressure in Dallas TX is only about 50 psig (345 kPa g).
Also note that this pressure rise cannot happen if houses are fitted with tankless water heaters only. I am not sure what happens with a "combination boiler" which heats domestic hot water.

Also happens if you have a pressure tank but its has lost its air charge, so it stops functioning. Homeowners virtually never check and refill them as they're supposed to, the pressure goes way too low and the bladder eventually bursts.

If your mains pressure is only 50 psi, and the city doesn't have check valves at the meter, how do they prevent users from contaminating the supply? Eg if I have a dirty hot water heater and the pressure rises in the scenario you describe, wouldn't that result in me pushing dirty water back into the mains?

@Tim The risk has been considered acceptable because systems are clean and thermal backflow is small and would be diluted. The real reason for the interest in anti-backflow is counter-terrorism, where somebody pumps poison (or LSD) into the system. That's why the valves are placed in a public location and many cities require inspection and annual testing.

As stated water pressure increases with depth, for every additional 2.31 feet (0.70 metre) of elevation (depth), water pressure will increase 1 psi (pound per square inch) (6.89 kPa) (for 1 metre, pressure increases by 10 kPa). Water pressure in distribution systems is dynamic, constantly changing due to the elevation, demand and pressure losses associated with the flow rate and pipe size. Typical distribution system pressure and flow will experience a diurnal curve due to the similarities in our daily patterns.  The lowest pressures will occur in the early morning, recover by 10 AM, repeat to a lessor degree around the dinner hour and max out around 3 AM when storage reservoirs are filled. Daily distribution system pressure fluctuations are expected and can easily be 10-25 PSI (70–170 kPa) or more.  As much as is possible, the home owner is responsible for maintaining the pressure within his home.  Too high a pressure is damaging to appliances, fixtures, and the piping.  A Pressure Reducing Valve and Expansion Tank or Pressure Sustaining Valve are typical residential plumbing devices designed to help regulate pressures.  Backflow Prevention devices add an additional dynamic as it relates to water expansion and fluctuating pressures.  All these devices require maintenance and have a limited life expectancy. I would recommend that you purchase a water pressure test gauge with a recording lazy hand for $15-$20 so that you can observe actual pressures.

As stated where? If you're referencing another answer, please specify that and link to it. If you're referring to a comment, those are temporary and shouldn't be referenced. Also, paragraphs are appreciated by tired eyes. Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Utilities usually specify the minimum pressure
Putting aside that the nominated pressure is at a specific point in their network and your house is almost certainly somewhere else, network pressures are dynamic.
Your being somewhere else will mean that the elevation may be different - if you are lower, the pressure will be higher and vice-versa. In addition, if you are closer to the source than the nominated point, there will be less frictional losses and vice-versa.
Notwithstanding, pressures in an active water network are dynamic.
Most networks try to use gravity rather than pumps to maintain pressure, because gravity keeps working when the electricity doesn’t. So, there will be an elevated reservoir (a tank or a dam) and the pressure will change with the depth of water in this.
In addition, water flow is not constant, at some times of the day more water is being used, at others less. The more water flowing, the greater the frictional loss.
Water utilities therefore quote the worst case scenario - minimum storage and maximum flow. If you design a plumbing system to deal with that, it will work for everything. Sometimes you need a pressure reduction valve to deal with the best case scenarios.
